# How to display contents of directory in a file using bash

Tags: bash, cp

I would like to copy the file names of a directory into a spreadsheet.  I don't care about the contents of the files, just the names.  I'm going to use this command so that I can provide detailed documentation for specific applications.

I currently have: cp //server_name/path/* /d/path

I'm looking for something like >> or -print and file name to create and hold the names of the files stored in a directory; i.e.,

File name = file_list.csv

Contents of file :

word.exe
notepad.exe
etc.
etc.
etc.

Comment: Are you asking for [`ls(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ls/)?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: how about sub-directory? exclude ?

Comment: @CarlNorum I just want to ask the same... ls -1

Answer (score 1):

`ls your/dir/path/here > your/file/path/here`

Comment: Thanks!!!  I found pieces from this forum to get my answer; I did the following:

I first did a local directory change to the directory where I wanted my files to be:
cd /d/my_dir/sub_dir

Then I performed the below command:
ls -sl $1 //server_name/dir_1/subdir_2 > dir_list.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
DEST_PATH=/d/path/file_list.csv

cd <directory-with-file-names>
for f in *
do
    echo "$f" >> $DEST_PATH
done
```